# Error while using the Makefile option in Tensorflow

Tags: c++, makefile, tensorflow, bazel

So I have been trying to build a portable .a file for TF. So I decided to follow the instruction on how to use the Makefile option for TF found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/makefile).

After entering the last command ( make -f tensorflow/contrib/makefile/Makefile), I get the following error:

> error: invalid conversion from ‘tensorflow::uint64* {aka long long unsigned int*}’ to ‘google::protobuf::uint64* {aka long unsigned int*}’ [-fpermissive]

Is this a bug in TF?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, or is in the Makefile process. I would advice to run the program from a release branch instead that from the latest on master.

Or you can build the tensorflow library using bazel:

```
bazel build //tensorflow:libtensorflow.so
```

[There is a C++ example of how to use the c++ library](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/cc/tutorials/example_trainer.cc)

and this [is the bazel target to build it](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/cc/BUILD#L264).

The easiest thing to do would be to create a new directory in that folder and copy the bazel build target.

Comment: So I tried to create a shared library using bazel as you said. Would you happen to know who to use from outside the TF repo?

Comment: What do you mean? link it with a C++ program ? I added few more info

Comment: I am trying to integrate my TF code with an already existing C++ project. I can't use bazel, I have been trying to find a way around it.